# ckeditor 3 different body style for full page preview

Tags: styles, ckeditor, fullscreen

Is it possible to change body style when entering a full page preview in ckeditor 3. Maybe to set a different body style for full page than when it is not in a full page mode.
The reason for this is using ckeditor when viewing a web page on a larger screen with maximized browser... in that case it is very wide and it is hard to read the content. So I would like to add in body style (but only for full page mode) something like:

```
...
margin: 5%;
padding: 5%;
border: 1px dotted #666;
...
```

... that will give more text processor look to the content.

TNX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) is toggled to fullscreen mode it adds "**cke_maximized**" class to container span.

So you may apply styles for entire container span (body+toolbar) like:

```
.cke_maximized{
   margin: 5%;
   padding: 5%;
   border: 1px dotted #666;
}
```

or just for content body:

```
.cke_maximized iframe{
   margin: 5%;
   padding: 5%;
   border: 1px dotted #666;
}
```

Those are just examples and you may experiment and choose css selector that is more suitable for you .

**UPDATE 1:**

Sure, you can use javascript code if it is not enough for your purposes. You can use something like this:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;

editor.on("afterCommandExec", function(e){
  if(e.data.name == 'maximize'){
      // maximized
      if(e.data.command.state == CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON){
          // add special css class to body(e.editor.document.getBody())
      } else {
      // minimized
      // remove special css from body
      }  
  }
});
```

Comment: Tnx. @Aleh Zasypkin for this tip - I've tried it already but it is still not usefull... Close, but still not handy for production purpose. Because iframe is hardcoded to 100% width and 100% height (can be changed in ckeditor.js) the space for body content is even larger. The style cke_maximized is added but with this one you can not control the content inside iframe. The best way would be some javascript that would change or add the style of body content inside of iframe on maximize event.

Comment: Yes, in a such cases you don't have other option than JS code. Please, see my update above.

Comment: THANKS Aleh! I was in the same time run into that kind of solution. Works like a charm.... You helped a lot!